# Javascript Object Properties accessing technique

Tags: javascript

I am a bit of new to Javascript and I had a bit of confusion. 
Now for a Javascript object as the one below:

```
var obj = {
    value:null
    };
obj[value] = 2;
```

The above code would give me an error at line 2.

But if replace it as below

```
obj.value = 2;
```

it would work. Can some one tell me the issue behind why this happens.

Comment: It should be `obj["value"]=2`

Comment: Vote to close as typographycal error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `obj["value"] = 2` like below

```js
var obj = { value: null };

obj["value"] = 2;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place "" around the value.

```
var obj = {
     value:null
     };
obj["value"] = 2;
```